# Building on work from previous MSE question 2306650 (Re: Odd Perfect Numbers)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, proof-verification, perfect-numbers

(Note:  This post builds on work from this previous [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2306650).)

Let $\sigma(N)$ denote the *sum of the divisors* of the natural number $N$.  If $\sigma(N)=2N$ and $N$ is odd, then $N$ is called an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers).  Denote the *abundancy index* $I$ of $N$ as $I(N)=\sigma(N)/N$.

Euler proved that every odd perfect number $N$ has to have the form $N=q^k n^2$ where $q$ is prime with $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

In this [paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.pdf), Dris proved that we have the bounds
$$L(q) = \frac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q-1)} = 3 - \frac{q-2}{q(q-1)} < I_{+} \leq 3 - \frac{q-1}{q(q+1)} = \frac{3q^2 + 2q + 1}{q(q+1)} = U(q)$$
for the sum of the abundancy indices $I_{+}=I(q^k)+I(n^2)$.  In particular, if $I_{+} \leq 3 - \epsilon$, then we will have $L(q) < 3 - \epsilon$, so that (using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+epsilon+%3C+(q+-+2)%2F(q%5E2+-+q)+for+q)) we get
$$\frac{\epsilon + 1}{2\epsilon}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{{\epsilon}^2 - 6\epsilon + 1}{{\epsilon}^2}} < q < \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{{\epsilon}^2 - 6\epsilon + 1}{{\epsilon}^2}}+\frac{\epsilon + 1}{2\epsilon}$$
if $0 < \epsilon < 3 - 2\sqrt{2}$.

Here is the problem:

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

> Does the converse hold?  That is, if $N=q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number, does
>   $$\frac{\epsilon + 1}{2\epsilon}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{{\epsilon}^2 - 6\epsilon + 1}{{\epsilon}^2}} < q < \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{{\epsilon}^2 - 6\epsilon + 1}{{\epsilon}^2}}+\frac{\epsilon + 1}{2\epsilon},$$
>   with $0 < \epsilon < 3 - 2\sqrt{2}$, imply that $I(q^k) + I(n^2) \leq 3 - \epsilon$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Assume that $$\frac{\epsilon + 1}{2\epsilon}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{{\epsilon}^2 - 6\epsilon + 1}{{\epsilon}^2}} < q < \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{{\epsilon}^2 - 6\epsilon + 1}{{\epsilon}^2}}+\frac{\epsilon + 1}{2\epsilon},$$
with $0 < \epsilon < 3 - 2\sqrt{2}$, and suppose to the contrary that
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) > 3 - \epsilon.$$

This means that $U(q) > 3 - \epsilon$, so that (by using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+epsilon+%3E+(q+-+1)%2F(q%5E2+%2B+q)+for+q) again) we obtain (for $0 < \epsilon < 3 - 2\sqrt{2}$) either
$$q > \frac{\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{1}{{\epsilon}^2} - \frac{6}{\epsilon} + 1} -
 1\bigg)\epsilon + 1}{2\epsilon},$$
or
$$0 < q < \frac{1-\epsilon}{2\epsilon} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{{\epsilon}^2 - 6\epsilon + 1}{{\epsilon}^2}}.$$

Here is my question:

> Do the resulting inequalities
>   $$q > \frac{\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{1}{{\epsilon}^2} - \frac{6}{\epsilon} + 1} -
>  1\bigg)\epsilon + 1}{2\epsilon},$$
>   or
>   $$0 < q < \frac{1-\epsilon}{2\epsilon} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{{\epsilon}^2 - 6\epsilon + 1}{{\epsilon}^2}},$$
>   for $0 < \epsilon < 3 - 2\sqrt{2}$, contradict the assumption
>   $$\frac{\epsilon + 1}{2\epsilon}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{{\epsilon}^2 - 6\epsilon + 1}{{\epsilon}^2}} < q < \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{{\epsilon}^2 - 6\epsilon + 1}{{\epsilon}^2}}+\frac{\epsilon + 1}{2\epsilon}?$$