# If $N=q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number and $q = k$, why does this bound not imply $q > 5$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, conjectures, perfect-numbers

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of natural numbers (i.e., positive integers).

A number $N \in \mathbb{N}$ is said to be *perfect* if $\sigma(N)=2N$, where $\sigma=\sigma_{1}$ is the classical sum of divisors.  For example, $\sigma(6)=1+2+3+6=2\cdot{6}$, so that $6$ is perfect.  (Note that $6$ is even.)  Denote the *abundancy index* of $x \in \mathbb{N}$ as $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

Euler proved that an odd perfect number $N$, if any exists, must take the form $N=q^k n^2$, where $q$ is prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Suppose that $k=q$.  Since $q$ is prime and $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, this implies that $k \geq 5$.  (In particular, $k \neq 1$, so that the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture is false in this case.)

Using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maximize%20(q%5E(q%2B1)%20-%201)%2F((q%5Eq)(q%20-%201))%20for%20q%20%3E%3D%205), we get the upper bound
$$I(q^k)=I(q^q)=\frac{q^{q+1}-1}{{q^q}(q-1)} \leq \frac{3906}{3125} = 1.24992$$
which corresponds to the lower bound
$$I(n^2)=\frac{2}{I(q^k)} \geq \frac{3125}{1953} \approx 1.6001\ldots.$$
Consider the product
$$\bigg(I(q^q) - \frac{3906}{3125}\bigg)\bigg(I(n^2) - \frac{3906}{3125}\bigg).$$
This product is nonpositive.  Therefore,
$$I(q^q)I(n^2) + \bigg(\frac{3906}{3125}\bigg)^2 \leq \frac{3906}{3125}\cdot\bigg(I(q^q) + I(n^2)\bigg).$$
Since $N=q^k n^2$ is perfect with $q=k$, then $I(q^k)I(n^2)=I(q^q)I(n^2)=2$, so that
$$I(q^q) + I(n^2) \geq \frac{3906}{3125} + \frac{3125}{1953} = \frac{17394043}{6103125} \approx 2.850022406554\ldots.$$

But in the paper [[Dris, 2012 (pages 4 to 5)]](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.pdf), it is proved that
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) \leq \frac{3q^2 + 2q + 1}{q(q+1)} = 3 - \frac{q-1}{q(q+1)}$$
with equality occurring if and only if $k=1$.

In our case, since $k = q \geq 5$, we obtain
$$\frac{17394043}{6103125} \leq I(q^q) + I(n^2) = I(q^k) + I(n^2) < 3 - \frac{q-1}{q(q+1)}$$
[which implies that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%203-((q-1)%2F(q(q%2B1)))%20%3E%20(17394043%2F6103125)%20for%20q)
$$q > \frac{3125}{781} \approx 4.00128\ldots.$$

Here is my question:

> Why does the bound 
>   $$I(q^q) + I(n^2) \geq \frac{3906}{3125} + \frac{3125}{1953} = \frac{17394043}{6103125} \approx 2.850022406554\ldots$$
>   *not imply* that $q > 5$?

I am thinking along the lines that:

> > **(1)** $57/20 < I(q^k) + I(n^2) < 3$ is best-possible.
> >
> > **(2)** Improving the upper bound $3$ would result in a finite upper bound for the Euler prime $q$.
> >
> > **(3)** Therefore, improving the lower bound $57/20$ would result in a lower bound for $q$ better than the currently known $q \geq 5$.

**REFERENCES**
[If $N=q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number, does $q \leq 97$ imply that $I(q^k)+I(n^2) \leq 2.99$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2306650)

Comment: I don't understand what your concern is. $3-\frac{q-1}{q(q+1)}>\frac{57}{20}$ leads to $q>4$, whereas your minimally better $3-\frac{q-1}{q(q+1)}>\frac{57}{20}+0.0000224\ldots$ leads to the minimally better $q>4.00128\ldots$ (and both are equivalent to $q\ge 5$). I do not see why you expect a major jump from such minimal improvement.

Comment: This comment is not directly related with your question. Just a calculation that is feasible on assumption of more conditions! If $n=q^qm^2$ is an odd perfect number then $$\frac{q^{q+1}-1}{q-1}\sigma(m^2)=2q^qm^2.\tag{1}$$ Thus from Euler-Fermat's theorem *for each positive integer* $t$ **satisfying** $\varphi(t)=q+1$ (where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function) **and** $q\nmid t$, *one has* $2(q^q-1)m^2\equiv 0\text{ mod } t$. I hope this claim is right, but it says nothing about your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that it has got something to do with the *interaction* between the conditions $k=1$ and $q=5$.

When $k=1$, we have the bounds
$$I(q^k)=I(q)=1+\frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{6}{5}$$
and
$$I(n^2)=\frac{2}{I(q)} \geq \frac{5}{3}.$$

When $q=5$, we have the [bounds](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01868.pdf)
$$I(n^2) \leq 2 - \frac{5}{3q} = \frac{5}{3}$$
and
$$I(q^k) \geq \frac{6}{5}.$$

Note that, when $k=1$, we have the lower bound
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) \geq \frac{43}{15} = 2.8\overline{666} > 2.85.$$
By the contrapositive, $I(q^k) + I(n^2) < 43/15$ implies that $k \neq 1$.  (Notice that the inequality $I(q^k) + I(n^2) < 43/15$ also implies $q = 5$.)

Note further that, when $q=5$, we have the upper bound
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) \leq \frac{43}{15}.$$
By the contrapositive, $I(q^k) + I(n^2) > 43/15$ implies that $q > 5$.

**Added July 17 2017**

> It turns out that $q > 5$ is *equivalent* to $I(q^k) + I(n^2) > 43/15$.