# On the golden ratio and odd perfect numbers

Tags: number-theory, inequality, divisor-sum, golden-ratio, perfect-numbers

Here is my question:

> Is $I(n^2) - 1 > 1/I(n^2)$ true when $I(n^2)=\sigma(n^2)/n^2$ is the abundancy index of $n^2$ and $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $k>1$?

**My Attempt**

If $k>1$, then since $q$ is the special prime, then $q$ satisfies $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  In particular, we know that $q \geq 5$ and $k \geq 5$.

We know that
$$I(q^k) = \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{q^k} = \frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{q^k (q - 1)} < \frac{q^{k+1}}{q^k (q - 1)} = \frac{q}{q - 1} \leq \frac{5}{4}.$$

It follows that
$$I(n^2) = \frac{2}{I(q^k)} > \frac{2(q - 1)}{q} \geq \frac{8}{5}.$$

Thus,
$$I(n^2) - 1 > \frac{2(q - 1)}{q} - 1 = \frac{(2q - 2) - q}{q} = \frac{q - 2}{q} > \frac{q}{2(q - 1)} > \frac{1}{I(n^2)}$$
where the inequality
$$\frac{q - 2}{q} > \frac{q}{2(q - 1)}$$
holds provided $q > 3+\sqrt{5} \approx 5.23607$.

However, the resulting inequality for $I(n^2)$ from
$$I(n^2) - 1 > \frac{1}{I(n^2)}$$
together with the following upper bound for $I(n^2)$ (which holds when $k>1$)
$$\frac{2q}{q+1} > I(n^2)$$
only yields
$$\frac{2q}{q+1} > I(n^2) > \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$$
thereby giving
$$q > \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{3-\sqrt{5}} = 2+\sqrt{5} \approx 4.23607.$$

Comment: Note that there is no *discrepancy* when $k=1$, as then we have
$$I(n^2) - 1 \geq \frac{2}{3} > \frac{3}{5} \geq \frac{1}{I(n^2)}$$
yielding the lower bound $q > 2 + \sqrt{5} \approx 4.23607$ from
$$\frac{2q}{q+1}=I(n^2) > \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}.$$

Comment: When $k>1$, we get
$$I(n^2) - 1 > \frac{3}{5} \not\gt \frac{5}{8} > \frac{1}{I(n^2)}.$$

Comment: Consider the case when $k > 1$.  If $q > 5$, then since $q$ is a prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, it follows that $q \geq 13$, from which we obtain
$$I(q^k) < \frac{q}{q - 1} \leq \frac{13}{12},$$
so that we get
$$I(n^2) = \frac{2}{I(q^k)} > \frac{24}{13} = 1.\overline{846153},$$
which vastly improves on
$$I(n^2) > \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2} \approx 1.61803.$$

Comment: It is now known that $I(n^2) > \zeta(2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full answer to the original question.

Let $q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$.  Furthermore, let $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ be the abundancy index of the positive integer $x$.  (Note that $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of divisors of $x$.)

Since the inequality
$$I(n^2) - 1 > \frac{1}{I(n^2)}$$
holds when $q>5$ or when $k=1$, it suffices to show that the inequality does not hold when $q=5$ and $k>1$.

First, note that the inequality
$$I(n^2) - 1 > \frac{1}{I(n^2)}$$
implies that
$$I(n^2) > \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2} \approx 1.61803.$$

Next, from the following [answer to a related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3107033/28816), we have:

Cohen and Sorli ruled out $5^5$ as a possible Eulerian component $q^k$ for an odd perfect number in page 4 of their paper titled [On Odd Perfect Numbers and Even 3-Perfect Numbers](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/a6self/a6self.pdf).

Thus, under the assumption $q=5$ and $k>1$, we have that $k \geq 9$ (since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$), whereupon we obtain
$$I(n^2) = \frac{2}{I(q^k)} \leq \frac{2}{I(5^9)} \leq \frac{1953125}{1220703} \approx 1.60000016384,$$
resulting in a contradiction.

Hence, the inequality
$$I(n^2) - 1 > \frac{1}{I(n^2)}$$
does not hold when $q=5$ and $k>1$.

**QED**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer for what happens when $k=1$.

We initially have
$$I(n^2) - 1 = \frac{2q}{q+1} - 1 = \frac{q-1}{q+1} > \frac{q+1}{2q} = \frac{1}{I(n^2)},$$
where the inequality
$$\frac{q-1}{q+1} > \frac{q+1}{2q}$$
holds when
$$q > 2+\sqrt{5} \approx 4.23607.$$

In particular, the inequality
$$I(n^2) - 1 > \frac{1}{I(n^2)}$$
holds when $q \geq 5$.

Unfortunately, the inequality
$$I(n^2) - 1 > \frac{1}{I(n^2)}$$
implies that $I(n^2) > \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2} \approx 1.61803$, whereas $k=1$ implies that
$$I(q^k)=I(q)=\frac{\sigma(q)}{q}=\frac{q+1}{q}=1+\frac{1}{q} \leq 1+\frac{1}{5}=\frac{6}{5}$$
(since $q \geq 5$), from which we obtain
$$I(n^2)=\frac{2}{I(q^k)}=\frac{2}{I(q)}\geq \frac{5}{3} = 1.\overline{666}.$$