# On the golden ratio and even perfect numbers

Tags: number-theory, inequality, divisor-sum, golden-ratio, perfect-numbers

(Note:  This post is an offshoot of this [earlier MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3123515).)

Here is my question in this post:

> Is $I(2^{p-1}) - 1 > 1/I(2^{p-1})$ true when $I(2^{p-1}) = \sigma(2^{p-1})/2^{p-1}$ is the abundancy index of $2^{p-1}$ and $6 \neq 2^{p-1}(2^p - 1)$ is an even perfect number (with corresponding Mersenne prime $2^p - 1$)?

**MY ATTEMPT**

**Claim** For $p \geq 3$,
$$\frac{7}{4} \leq I(2^{p-1}) < 2.$$

> *Proof:* Only the left-hand inequality is not evident (as $2^{p-1}$ is *deficient*, being a *proper divisor* of the *perfect number* $2^{p-1}(2^p - 1)$).
> $$I(2^{p-1}) = \frac{\sigma(2^{p-1})}{2^{p-1}} = \frac{2^p - 1}{2^{p-1}} = 2 - \bigg(\frac{1}{2^{p-1}}\bigg).$$
> But since $6 \neq 2^{p-1}(2^p - 1)$, then $p \geq 3$, which implies that
> $$2^{p-1} \geq 4 \implies \frac{1}{2^{p-1}} \leq \frac{1}{4} \implies 2 - \bigg(\frac{1}{2^{p-1}}\bigg) \geq 2 - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{7}{4}.$$
> **QED**

Checking now whether this inequality is satisfied:
$$I(2^{p-1}) - 1 > \frac{1}{I(2^{p-1})}$$

For $p \geq 3$:
$$I(2^{p-1}) - 1 \geq \frac{3}{4} > \frac{4}{7} \geq \frac{1}{I(2^{p-1})}.$$

For general $p$:
$$I(2^{p-1}) - 1 = 1 - \bigg(\frac{1}{2^{p-1}}\bigg) = \frac{2^{p-1} - 1}{2^{p-1}}$$
$$\frac{1}{I(2^{p-1})} =  \frac{2^{p-1}}{2^p - 1}$$
$$\bigg(I(2^{p-1}) - 1\bigg) - \frac{1}{I(2^{p-1})} = \frac{2^{p-1} - 1}{2^{p-1}} - \frac{2^{p-1}}{2^p - 1} > 0 \text{ when } p \geq 3.$$

**Note that, since $I(2^{p-1})=x$ satisfies the inequality
$$I(2^{p-1}) - 1 > \frac{1}{I(2^{p-1})} \iff x - 1 > \frac{1}{x} \implies x^2 - x - 1 > 0 \text{ since } x > 1 > 0 \implies x > \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} = \varphi \approx 1.618,$$
which is trivial compared to the inequality
$$I(2^{p-1})=x \geq \frac{7}{4} = 1.75.$$**

*Finally, notice that $6 = 2^{2 - 1} \cdot (2^2 - 1)$ was excluded in this analysis because it is squarefree.*

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that your attempt does not prove that the inequality is true?

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove!  My attempt *does* appear to  prove that the inequality is true, since (at the very least) the numerical inequality in the middle of
$$I(2^{p-1}) - 1 \geq \frac{3}{4} > \frac{4}{7} \geq \frac{1}{I(2^{p-1})}$$
holds.

Comment: I think so too. I've found no errors in the inequalities. (To be honest, I don't understand what you are trying to do after the inequalities since it seems to me that you already answered your question.)

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, @mathlove!  The whole point of this question was to compare the case of *even perfect numbers*, with that of *odd perfect numbers*, as detailed out in the [hyperlinked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3123515).

Comment: @mathlove:  Please write an answer and include your confirmation that you have found no error in the inequalities, so that I may be able to upvote and accept (and so that this question does not remain in the unanswered queue).  Thanks!  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written a proof for the follwing claim :

**Claim** For $p \geq 3$, $\frac{7}{4} \leq I(2^{p-1}).$

> $$2^{p-1} \geq 4 \implies \frac{1}{2^{p-1}} \leq \frac{1}{4} \implies 2 - \bigg(\frac{1}{2^{p-1}}\bigg) \geq 2 - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{7}{4}.$$

I've found no errors here.

(One can also say "Since $I(2^{p-1})$ is increasing, we have $I(2^{p-1})\ge I(2^{3-1})=\frac 74$".)

After this, you have written

> For $p \geq 3$:$$I(2^{p-1}) - 1 \geq \frac{3}{4} > \frac{4}{7} \geq \frac{1}{I(2^{p-1})}.$$

I've found no errors here.

In conclusion, I think that you have correctly proved the inequality.